# Xamarin forms receive control centre event while playing songs in background

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, control-center

I am using [plugin](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) in xamarin to play songs on iOS and Android device which is working out perfectly.My problem is that I am unable to find way to listen to next and previous button press in control centre.

[image]

I have read [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/) for reference,but it doesn't seem to provide enough info to achieve solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the related information in its [README.md](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager#important).

> - If you want to enable RemoteControl features, you will have to
>     override `UIApplication.RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent)` and forward the
>     event to the
>     `MediaManagerImplementation.MediaRemoteControl.RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent)`
>     method. See the sample application for more details.

Follow these steps:

1. Create a SampleApplication class inherit from UIApplication To implement `RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent)` as its [sample code](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/blob/develop/Samples/Simple/MediaSample.iOS/SampleApplication.cs), like this:

   ```
   using Foundation;
   using Plugin.MediaManager;
   using UIKit;

   namespace MediaSample.iOS
   {
       [Register("SampleApplication")]
       public class SampleApplication: UIApplication
       {
           private MediaManagerImplementation MediaManager => (MediaManagerImplementation) CrossMediaManager.Current;

           public override void RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent uiEvent)
           {               
              MediaManager.MediaRemoteControl.RemoteControlReceived(uiEvent);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   `MediaManager.MediaRemoteControl.RemoteControlReceived(uiEvent)` helps you to handle the next/previous/pause/play events. To see how it works, you can refer [here](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/blob/f4025faadcc7ead9d3e8487449db0b0e5d34b108/MediaManager.iOS/MediaRemoteControl.cs#L26).
2. Don't foget to add the SampleApplication to `UIApplication.Main()` in Main.cs like this:

   ```
    UIApplication.Main(args, "SampleApplication", "AppDelegate");
   ```